# Can host variables in IBM i SQL have spaces?

Tags: ibm-midrange, cobol, rpg

Is it possible to provide space between colon and variable name when using host variables in RPG/COBOL embedded SQL.

I have never encountered a space in any example programs.

Comment: I do not have the relevant language reference manual to hand but that is where you should look. How to define a host variable will be defined in that manual (SQL Language Reference).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not really that hard to test...

Yes.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The variable itself cannot though, for obvious reasons. Also keep in mind, **when embedding variables, you cannot do so for a multiple value string in an IN() operator**. It doesn't parse properly.